# Circular referencing in Symfony forms

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I am currently building a Symfony 4.4 API that is capable of adding objects to a database. Since I believe that my problem can be explained and resolved using only theory I won't add my actual code here but I'll provide a more conceptual description.

I have an entity class named `Person`. This class has a corresponding form, called `PersonType`. A person could have a user and an employee linked to it. These also have their entities and forms.

A user has a field called `createdBy` which links to another user and an employee must have a person linked to it.

My problem is that when I try to patch a person using the usual way (`createForm()` and Doctrine, like [here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/forms.html#processing-forms)), I get a memory overflow at `createForm()`. When I remove the references to `UserType` and `EmployeeType` from `PersonType`, there is no memory overflow. My memory size is 1GB, and I believe making it larger will not resolve the issue.

Is there is a way to limit the number of circular references, or to prevent the rendering of the person of the employee of the person, for example.

Comment: Do you actually need to expose `createdBy` to the form? Can't you set it from the controller on creation?

Comment: @msg that's a good idea, thanks! I suppose it isn't necessary. However, even if I remove only the user field and leave in the employee field, I'll still get the memory overflow.

Comment: I think you might need to dig a bit deeper.  Unless you have some sort of eager loading going on then there is no inherent reason why what you described should result in a circular error.  You might try creating a DQL query which fetches the exact entities needed.  That will prevent any kind of lazy loading that might be messing you up.

Comment: Showing your form type(s) may help, are you using just `PersonType` with additional `PersonType` embedded?

Comment: @ArleighHix I don't have a ```PersonType``` embedded in ```PersonType```, although I do have ```EmployeeType``` embedded in ```PersonType```, and ```EmployeeType``` embeds ```PersonType``` (since I'd also like to be able to edit a person using its employee - at some points I want mainly the employee and at other points mainly the person).

Comment: @Cerad thanks for the suggestion, I'll definitely look into that, it might take a while though.